# como llenar un datagridview con un split

Tags: vb.net

realizar un split de un combobox que contiene un strig como este  **(xy’ + xz)’ + x'** y que me llene el grid con las columnas xy’, xz y x 
la cadena puede contener n cantidad de letras.

```vb
Public Sub split()
    Dim input As String = Me.txtfuncion.Text.ToString() & Convert.ToChar(8)
    Dim pattern As String = "(y)(x)(%+)"
    Dim items() As String = input.Split(pattern) 'c')
    'Dim cod As String = item(0)
    Dim cantidad As Integer = 0
    cantidad = items.Count - 1

Try
    For Each result As String In items(cantidad)

    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("ingrese una expresion algebraica")
End Try



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es obtener los nombres de variables de la expresión (extraer los conjuntos de letras) puedes utilizar expresiones regulares.

Dando por hecho que el DataGridView tiene un número suficiente de columnas podría ser algo así:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim input = txtfuncion.Text
    Dim regVars = new Regex("\w+")
    Dim matches = regVars.Matches(input)
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(matches.Cast(Of Match).Select(Function(m) m.Value).ToArray())
End Sub
```